# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable - but is a list

Tags: python

I have a list of lists that I want to iterate over for reasons later in the project. However, when I try to iterate over each list in the normal, pythonic way, I get an the error `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`. So, to test how the code was working I wrote

```
for i in self.features:
  print(i)
  print("Test1")

for i in len(self.features):
  print(i)
  print("Test2")
```

The program is successfully able to execute all the items in the Test1 loop, and none in the second. For the first test the output is:

```
Test1
2      169.091522
3      171.016678
4      170.381485
5      170.361954
6      170.322845
 ....
245    149.510544
246    145.642090
247    155.898438
248    154.886688
249    154.966034
Name: Adj Close, Length: 248, dtype: float64
```

So, features seems to be a list of lists, just like I had wanted, but it appears to not want to allow me to do the things you can typically do with a list.

To see the code in action, you can run it here
https://repl.it/@JacksonEnnis/KNNFinalProduct

Comment: len(self.features) is an int

Comment: `len(self.features)` is an `int`

Comment: `len(self.features)` return integer object/value ? why you expect it is iterable ?

Comment: Yes but the second test does not run - why wouldn't it print i?

Comment: @JacksonEnnis It fails with an error before `i` gets assigned a value `in` the (non) sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`len()` returns the length of a list as an `int`. Python will be interpreting your code as:

```
for i in 5:
  print(i)
  print("Test2")
```

It will fail when interpreting the `for` statement and will never enter the loop.

---

To correctly iterate over the list your first snippet is correct.

```
for i in self.features:
  print(i)
  print("Test1")
```

---

If you wanted to iterate through a range of numbers up to the size of your list, you should use `range()`.

```
for i in range(1, len(self.features) + 1):
  print(i)
  print("Test2")
```

As suggested by @PeterWood you could also use `enumerate()`.

```
for i, _ in enumerate(self.features, 1):
  print(i)
  print("Test2")
```

Comment: [**`enumerate`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) is nice.

Comment: or `for i,f in enumerate(self.features): print(i)`